# Where is php config and .htaccess located on Raspbian?

Tags: apache-httpd, raspbian, php5

I am trying to change the upload limit of my owncloud installation. A raspberry pi and the Raspbian OS are powering this server. Apparently I can edit the php config or the .htaccess config but I am unsure of where either of those are located. It says .htaccess is located inside the owncloud install directory. And the php config is here `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` . But when I use nano to edit the php config it's blank. I am pretty sure it exists somewhere because My owncloud installation is working and I can upload small files. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: In terminal try: `locate php.ini` Or `whereis php` and then look around. Or doing a google search for "where is php.ini located" might come up with a lot of good results. I would also downvote, but you get the idea. The reason being is that this question has been asked and resolved many times and doing a little more research on your part with some internet searches would find something?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/dude-wheres-my-php-ini

Comment: locate php returns bash error. When typing whereis (with either just php or php.ini) it locates php files, but not the php.ini file that I need. Trust me I have tried googling, I will try some more though. This is where I get really frustrated. I didn't just come here first thing, I have been trying to figure this out for 2 hours straight, so yeah I figured it would be worthwhile to ask, because someone that knows could answer in a second.

Comment: See the link that i posted above. And it would be `locate php.ini` which includes the file extension. Its a nice way to find files in the system. You could also use `find . | grep ini` in directories that you think it might be. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much that link worked i used this one, php -i | grep 'php.ini' . You shouldn't be so quick to judge. I could have spent another hour googling, and believe me I have been trying, but you saved me so much time. The internet is very vast, just because you search google doesn't mean you will find what you need right away. google results are based on keywords, and those are infinitely variable. Also that answer was on stack overflow, theres way too much elitism there for me to even bother wasting my time with. If you wouldn't mind making it an answer, and If not I will.

Comment: Totally. It was just the thought that was run was running through my mind at the time. That is why included the search that I used, because I find it hard to know which words I should put together to do a search sometimes too. Help yourself to answering the question. Im glad that you found it. I will also keep that in mind the next time that I comment.

Comment: Also I guess taking a less hostile stance is also encouraged here. Finger pointing and that kind of stuff generally doesn't get very far. So if I were you I would consider editing my question and just removing that, but that is just me.

Comment: I have found that if I do my research and ask a well formed question with formatted code blocks, and if its specific enough, someone may be kind enough to take the time out of their day to answer my question on stackoverflow, but I totally understand your gripes about the attitudes there sometimes. Also consider adding which version of raspbian you are using so if anyone else in the future comes along they may also find it of use.